# Помощь в расстановке циклов python

Tags: python, циклы, for, переменные

Всем доброго времени суток! Недавно я начал изучать python, не судите строго. Вопрос более для того чтобы начать коммуникацию с единомышленниками и по-тихоньку внедряться во все плюшки типа stackoverflow. Понимаю что вопрос совсем легкий, но повторюсь я решил спросить у Вас, для общего кругозора.

Вкратце, я начал проходить небольшой курс по python, но математические задачи меня в нем убивают...
Решил попробовать написать небольшую игру.
Игра называется "1000", [Правила игры оставлю здесь](https://selosovetov.ru/2016/11/25/igra-v-1000/), в принципе алгоритм не сложный, но придется поковыряться, т.к. это мой первый проект.

Что я сделал на текущий момент:

```
from random import randint

points = 0
counter_1 = 0
counter_2 = 0
counter_3 = 0
counter_4 = 0
counter_5 = 0

print('Бросает Игрок_1')

for i in range(1, 6):
    drop = randint(1, 6)
    print(drop)
    if drop == 1:
        counter_1 += 1
    elif drop == 2:
        counter_2 += 1
    if counter_1 == 1:
        points += 10
    elif counter_1 == 2:
        points += 20
    elif counter_1 == 3:
        points += 100
    elif counter_1 == 4:
        points += 200
    elif counter_1 == 5:
        points += 1000
    elif counter_2 == 1:
        points += 0
    elif counter_2 == 2:
        points += 0
    elif counter_2 == 3:
        points += 20
    elif counter_2 == 4:
        points += 40
    elif counter_2 == 5:
        points += 200
print('Сумма очков броска =', points)
```

Сделал пока расчет для двух цифр. Чтобы не удлинять абракадабру.

Я полностью осознаю корявость своего кода и наверняка его можно уместить короче, но в данный момент мне важно понять структуру отступов, потому что при запуске идет не совсем правильный расчет очков. При выпадании двух единиц выпадает 30, а должно 20.
Спасибо большое тем кто отнесется с пониманием и откликнется на мой зов помощи.

Всем добра!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Главным недостатком вашего кода является то, что ваш код сразу после броска *каждого отдельного кубика* пытается анализировать, не зная, что будет дальше.

Сделайте сначала броски **всех 5 кубиков**, и только после этого анализируйте.

Я не знаю степень ваших знаний в Питоне, потому буду пользоваться только тем, что я увидел в вашем коде.

И так, сначала бросаем 5 кубиков:

```
for _ in range(5):           # нагладнее, чем ваше range(1, 6); вместо i я дал _
    drop = randint(1, 6)
    print(drop)
    if drop == 1:
        counter_1 += 1
    elif drop == 2:
        counter_2 += 1
    elif drop == 3:
        counter_3 += 1
    elif drop == 4:
        counter_4 += 1
    elif drop == 5:
        counter_5 += 1
    elif drop == 6:
        counter_6 += 1
```

**Конец вашего цикла `for`!**

Но и теперь вы можете анализировать результат, уже **не** в цикле, а после него. Значит, **без отступов**:

```
if counter_1 == 1:
    points += 10
elif counter_1 == 2:
    points += 20
elif counter_1 == 3:
    points += 100
...... и т.д. ......
```

Comment: Может быть, сразу получше сделать: `counters = [0]*7  ... counters[drop] += 1` ?

Comment: @MBo, вы пропустили один абзац в моем ответе. :-)

Comment: @MarianD Действительно, так код работает! Спасибо за доходчивый ответ!

Comment: @АлександрКорольков, не стоит. :-)

Comment: @MBo не совсем понимаю, как применить список, хотя знаю что он значительно должен скомпоновать код.

Comment: @MarianD Не сразу понял, что вы имеете в виду `потому буду пользоваться только тем, что я увидел в вашем коде`. Ну главное, что вы верно указали ключевую логическую ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

Для дальнейшего развития.

Учёл правила: 3-5 одинаковых, 1-2 единицы или пятерки, два стрита, повторы не делал.

Как упрощается со списками счётчиков, достоинств граней, ценности больших количеств. Это весь код.

```
from random import randint

cnt = [0]*7
for _ in range(5):
    drop = randint(1, 6)
    print(drop, end = ' ')
    cnt[drop] += 1

print(cnt)

result = 0
prices = [0, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
count_factors = [0, 0, 0, 10, 20, 100]
 
if cnt[2]*cnt[3]*cnt[4]*cnt[5]==1:
    result += 250 if cnt[1]==0 else 125
else:
    for i in range(1, 7):
        if i in [1,5] and cnt[i] in [1,2]:
            result += cnt[i] * prices[i]
        else:
            result += prices[i] * count_factors[cnt[i]]

print(result)
```

Примеры:

```
6 3 2 5 1 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
15

6 4 4 6 4 [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2]
40

2 5 1 1 1 [0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
105

3 1 4 5 2 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
125

1 1 1 1 1 [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1000
```